# Precise Swing Timer in Java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm developing an application where i need to execute a countdown, have a certain counter go down every second, and display in a widget.

No problem, that is done easily using the java class `javax.swing.Timer`, but the performance are poor.

There are other graphical object on screen and it is not accurate enough, letting it go down from 10 minute to 0 takes more than 10 minutes.

First thing i tried is a Timer with a 1000ms delay, that makes me lose a lot of seconds and sometimes it is not fast enough in updating the view.

Second, i tried with a Timer with a delay of 20ms and a logic inside that let my action run only if the `System.nanoTime()` report a second from last execution.

This gives me a better accuracy, but yet in an environment where the java application is in execution with other applications on old systems, it performs even worse.

Is there a way to achieve a scheduler indipendent Timer in Java? 
I'm up for really anything. OS indipendence isn't really an issue, so native code is an option if it gives me a good result.

**UPDATE:**

I created an example and uploaded it on gist:

https://gist.github.com/bracco23/c160c9591ac216a2eb9452ef9e7d6d95

Badly, the example isn't really as bad as the full project, i let it run for the full 10 minutes and it took about 602s, a 2s delay that's less than 0.4%, not really bad, i wouldn't mind that.

I'm uploading it to show the schema of the application, the same in the example and in the full application.

thank you very much anyway :D

Comment: 10 minutes to go down from 10 to 0 with a Timer executing every second? Something must be very very wrong in your code. But you didn't post any, so... all we can do is guess that you're freezing the UI somehow by executing time-consuming tasks in the EDT.

Comment: Please post your [mcve] so we can avoid guessing what you might be doing wrong (if you're doing anything wrong that is).

Comment: A `Timer` is not intended to be precise, and will drift over time. But not quite at that rate of drift, so like @HovercraftFullOfEels I recommend you post an MCVE. OTOH I would not do it this way. Instead I'd have the timer fire every 50 ms, and each time check the current time in milliseconds. If 1 second (or up to 1 second & 49 milliseconds) has passed, change the display to increment the second counter. The thing is, the user is not going to notice if the time the second changes is delayed (or faster) by 1/20th of a second, so it appears rock solid, and the clock keeps 'correct time'..

Comment: *"..i tried with a Timer with a delay of 20ms ..

This gives me a better accuracy, but yet in an environment where the java application is in execution with other applications on old systems, it performs even worse."* What the..? Perhaps you should share a [mcve] of that code for us to look at. I suspect their is a bug in it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: That is the correct approach; please post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the fact that everything inside my application runs on the EDT creates me problems. I'm not doing anything expensive myself, but with the extensive use i made of built-in Observer/Observable there may be some issue i can't see.